# "XdbContextLoggingPlugin" XdbContext Batch Execution Exception

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect, azure

I am getting an SQL exception in the XConnect application.

Error:

```
["XdbContextLoggingPlugin"] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception

XdbContextLoggingPlugin

MessageTemplate: [{0}] XdbContext Batch Execution Exception
Exception type: Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.FacetOperationException
Application: XConnect
```

The only changes I have done before getting this error are updating the license of the XC-Search web app.

For info, I am using Sitecore 9.2 in Azure PaaS.

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: yes.. no stack trace

Comment: Do you have any idea what code is calling this, meaning is it your custom facet searches or just Sitecore code.

Comment: how did you changed the license? Experience Profile is heavily using xconnect search API can you search for contacts in Experience Profile? does it show you anything?